# Linking data from one SharePoint List to Another

Tags: list, links-list

I would like to create another list (let's call it B) based on the first. List B would be linked to List A and show any and all changes to the item in List A to be reflected in List B. We also wish to have separate columns in List B that are not reflected in List A

Is this possible with out of the box functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a bit more detail but it sounds like you just need a workflow on list a than runs every time an item is edited. The workflow will then create a new item in list b copying all the fields.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like the most straightforward approach.  Add a lookup column to list B which references the list A item.